# R lmer and lmerTest: Why are my degrees of freedom in my output so low for model with stimuli and participants as random intercepts?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

I am having an issue understanding why my degrees of freedom are so low even though there is a decent number of participants in my study that is using lmer and lmerTest.

Here is my model:

`myMod <- lmer(dv ~ A + (1|Stim) + (1|Sub), data = myData)`

Where A is a 2-level factor, Stim = 14, and Subj = 155 (Nobs = 2163).

My output has t(12) = 4.4. But I'm wondering why it is collapsing in this way. Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` is a factor variable measuring an attribute of `Stim`, for which (apparently) you have only 14 groups, this is the sample size that counts for computing the degrees of freedom of `A` coefficient estimate.

Also you can see in [this paper](https://econtent.hogrefe.com/doi/abs/10.1027/1614-2241.1.3.86) that random effect is not a very good option if you have few second level-groups (less than 50), which is the case of `Stim = 14`. So it might be better if you should use random effects just for `Subj = 155`.

Comment: Maybe we would be able to help you with more insights, if you could show us the full output summary of your model, describe a little more your data structure, and also show us the first lines of your data with ```head(myData)```. From your code, I might deduce that you have two cross-classified second level groups [see this link](https://bit.ly/38hxoNl). Is that right? Which of the groups is A a factor of? (It would be better if I could ask this questions in comments first. But as I am a new user here, I could only comment in my own answer).